# TideSDK Developer unable to download?

Tags: tidesdk

I just downloaded TideSDK and it looks great. Saw that TideKit is upcoming :)

When I tried to start up their "Hello World" example it told me it had to install more packages. When downloading it hit what seems like to me a 404 error and it also got "no release found by that id" as response.

I did wait a few hours before retrying, but it doesn't seem to help..

So I was wondering if wether or not it's just me? Alternatively if anyone's seen these errors before and what they did to resolve...

Error: [Pasted here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b29fb247abf3654046ee)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the SDK runtime at proper location according to your operating system. Checkout  [Getting Started Guide](http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started) for details.